# Refactoring if-else in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a few keys that can be pressed, and each key press emits a signal that corresponds to it. However, the key presses do different things depending on which object is being operated on. I have an example illustration below.

```
// keyboard.cpp
void receive_key_press(uint8_t key_id){

    if(key_id == 1)
        emit key_one_pressed();
    else if(key_id == 2)
        emit key_two_pressed();
    else if(key_id == 3)
        emit key_three_pressed();
}
```

```
Class A : public QObject {
    // use Q_PROPERTY here to expose the member var 'model' to qml

    public:           
        int model; 
}

int main(){
    
    Keyboard keyboard;
    A obj;
    if (some_condition)
        obj.model = 5;
    else
        obj.model = 7;

    // Engine initialization here and exposing 'obj' and 'keyboard' to qml using setContextProperty
}
```

Then in main.qml

```
Connections {
    target: keyboard

    onKey_one_pressed: {
        if (obj.model == 5)
            // do something
        else
            // do something else

        // execute some common code here
    }

    onKey_two_pressed: {
        if (obj.model == 5)
            // do something
        else
            // do something else
    }

    onKey_three_pressed: {
        if (obj.model == 5)
            // do something
        else
            // do something else
    }
}
```

How can I simplify and avoid all those if-else conditions in the main.qml. Is there something in Qt that can make this easier, and provide some global way of handling a 'Gui state'. I know there's like a File Selector in Qt but that's not really what I'm going for. I want to have a better approach instead of having if-else everywhere in the Gui for different model.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear what you consider "better". Would moving the if-else conditions from `main.qml` to `keyboard.cpp` (and increasing the number of connections) be something you consider "better"? It does achieve your stated criterion ("avoid all those if-else conditions in the main.qml"). What constitutes "better" in your mind?

Comment: That is a good question. I might have been looking for a "magical" way to refactor it. What you mentioned is an option, but it's just a trade-off i guess. I was wondering if there was something like QQmlFileSelector, which in a way simplifies code that could otherwise be written with if-else. Basically my goal was to achieve it without writing the if-else in my code, maybe some Qt class abstracts it out for me (even though under the hood it might use if-else) and my code is cleaner..  but I'm realizing this might be too specific and optimistic of a question..

Answer (score 0):

In your particular example, factor it out into a common function:

```
Connections {
    target: keyboard

    function commonCode() {
        // execute some common code here
    }

    onKey_one_pressed: {
        if (obj.model == 5)
            // do something
        else
            // do something else

        commonCode();
    }

    onKey_two_pressed: {
        if (obj.model == 5)
            // do something
        else
            // do something else

        commonCode();
    }

    onKey_three_pressed: {
        if (obj.model == 5)
            // do something
        else
            // do something else

        commonCode();
    }
}
```

You can also put `commonCode` in a more broadly accessible place to further reduce code duplication.

However, there is also QML States: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-statesanimations-states.html

This is a very handy way to manage different configurations of your GUI. You can use `PropertyChanges` with it to override the signal handler of objects based on your model value.